# C++ app that runs after boot when a specific service is enabled cannot be stopped with systemctl stop

Tags: boot, services, c++, systemd

I have created a service on an Ubuntu 16.04 in order to run a c++ app after every boot.The service unit file I created and stored it under /etc/systemd/system/ is the following (app.service):

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/home/app/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The script.sh contains the following:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ep /home/app/C++_APP  
 cd /home/app
 ./C++_APP
```

When my c++ app is running and  I give systemctl stop npt.service the command does not ends its execution and the app is still running. Should I give an argument in execstop field that will kill the specific pid or is there a more efficient way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How `systemd` handles stopping and killing processes is covered in `man systemd.service` and `man systemd.kill`. If you are unsure how a particular directive works like `ExecStop=`, you can find the right man page that documents with `man systemd.directives`.

The documentation there will explain that the default behavior is to send a SIGTERM signal, wait 90 seconds and then send a SIGKILL signal.

If this behavior doesn't work for you, you can update your app to change how it responds to a SIGTERM signal, or you can review the options in referenced man pages to customize what happens when `systemd` issues a `stop` command.